# Failed UDEV rules test on Oracle Linux 7

Tags: rhel, oracle-linux, oracle-vm-server

I wrote my UDEV rules, to configure asm devices as shown:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB40696d3c-4b65a1e9", SYMLINK+="oracleasm/asm-disk1", OWNER="oracle", GROUP="dba", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB131c87f1-9a5b7135", SYMLINK+="oracleasm/asm-disk2", OWNER="oracle", GROUP="dba", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB3d0db51a-8fe749fa", SYMLINK+="oracleasm/asm-disk3", OWNER="oracle", GROUP="dba", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM=="/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB93d904b0-66a29d8f", SYMLINK+="oracleasm/asm-disk4", OWNER="oracle", GROUP="dba", MODE="0660"
```

But The following error pops up when test the first disk with this  `/sbin/udevadm test /block/sdb/sdb1`:

```
/sbin/udevadm test /block/sdb/sdb1

calling: test

version 219

This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          219
file size:         7014922 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1806418 bytes
nodes              5208424 bytes
Load module index
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/100-balloon.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-lvm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-mpath.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/13-dm-disk.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2.rules
IMPORT found builtin 'usb_id --export %%p', replacing /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2.rules:11
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-redhat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-rbd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/56-hpmud.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-alias-kmsg.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-fprint-autosuspend.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-raw.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxadd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-bluetooth-rfkill.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-settings-daemon-rfkill.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/62-multipath.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-md-incremental.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-sane-backends.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-dm-lvm-metad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-xorg-vmmouse.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-ipoib.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-spice-vdagentd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad-quirks.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-biosdevname.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-pcmcia-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-platform-serial-whitelist.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-telit-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-usb-serial-adapters-greylist.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-kvm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/81-kvm-rhel.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-nm-unmanaged.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-tools-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-iprutils.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-vconsole.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/91-drm-modeset.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-dm-notify.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-csr.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/98-kexec.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/98-rdma.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-qemu-guest-agent.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-vmware-scsi-timeout.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 32235 bytes strings
29804 strings (247631 bytes), 26864 de-duplicated (218337 bytes), 2941 trie nodes used
GROUP 6 /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:52
LINK 'disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b-part1' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:43
IMPORT builtin 'blkid' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:72
probe /dev/sdb1 raid offset=0
PROGRAM '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:1
starting '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'(out) '1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' [7840] exit with return code 0
OWNER 54321 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:1
GROUP 54322 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:1
MODE 0660 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:1
LINK 'oracleasm/asm-disk1' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:1
PROGRAM '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:2
starting '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'(out) '1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' [7841] exit with return code 0
PROGRAM '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:3
starting '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'(out) '1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' [7842] exit with return code 0
PROGRAM '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' /etc/udev/rules.d/99-oracle-asmdevices.rules:4
starting '/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb'(out) '1ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b'
'/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/sdb' [7843] exit with return code 0
handling device node '/dev/sdb1', devnum=b8:17, mode=0660, uid=54321, gid=54322
preserve permissions /dev/sdb1, 060660, uid=54321, gid=54322
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/block/8:17' to '../sdb1'
found 'b8:17' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2fdisk\x2fby-id\x2fata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b-part1'
creating link '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b-part1' to '/dev/sdb1'
preserve already existing symlink '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b-part1' to '../../sdb1'
found 'b8:17' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2foracleasm\x2fasm-disk1'
creating link '/dev/oracleasm/asm-disk1' to '/dev/sdb1'
creating symlink '/dev/oracleasm/asm-disk1' to '../sdb1'
atomically replace '/dev/oracleasm/asm-disk1'
***symlink '../sdb1' '/dev/oracleasm/asm-disk1.tmp-b8:17' failed: Operation not permitted***
created db file '/run/udev/data/b8:17' for '/block/sdb/sdb1'
.ID_FS_TYPE_NEW=
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b-part1 /dev/oracleasm/asm-disk1
DEVNAME=/dev/sdb1
DEVPATH=/block/sdb/sdb1
DEVTYPE=partition
ID_ATA=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM=1
ID_ATA_FEATURE_SET_PM_ENABLED=1
ID_ATA_SATA=1
ID_ATA_SATA_SIGNAL_RATE_GEN2=1
ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE=1
ID_ATA_WRITE_CACHE_ENABLED=1
ID_BUS=ata
ID_FS_TYPE=
ID_MODEL=VBOX_HARDDISK
ID_MODEL_ENC=VBOX\x20HARDDISK\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:16
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=10483712
ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0x83
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_REVISION=1.0
ID_SERIAL=VBOX_HARDDISK_VB35ea20aa-deda408b
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=VB35ea20aa-deda408b
ID_TYPE=disk
MAJOR=8
MINOR=17
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:systemd:
USEC_INITIALIZED=79251
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Any hints?

Comment: `PROGRAM` is an assignment key (`=`) not a match key (`==`) I think?

Comment: thank but the issue was with a different file, that is 99-vmware-scsi-timeout.rules